# What is the most efficent way to remove all element in AVL tree (sorted-removals)

Tags: algorithm, oop, data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

I know removing a node in AVL tree takes time complexity of O(logn). That being said, removing an AVL tree with n nodes would take O(n*logn). However, I am wondering if my goal is to have the sorted element of AVL tree that I could remove all elements in O(n) instead of O(n*logn). Possibly by implementing an remove element that would take O(1).
I was not able to find any way to do it in O(n). Is it because we can't or am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need to preserve AVL structure after every deletion, then perform [post-order traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal#Post-order_(LRN)), just deleting every node without balancing instead of "Display the data part"